# Android - Click in compose ListItem and get reference to its contents

Tags: android, material-design, android-compose

In the non-compose version I have something like the following:

```xml
(...)
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="my label"/>
    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="my text"/>
    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="my text2"/>
    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="my text3"/>
</LinearLayout>
(...)
```

And it repeats as many times as I need, representing a list of values with their respective texts, for example:

> **User settings**
>
> Active at home
>
> Active at office
>
> Inactive at lab

---

> **Server connected**
>
> [www.someserver.com](http://www.someserver.com)

---

> **Debug info**
>
> u5y4t3fweryhjy43tr2

etc.

And I have a helper function that runs whenever the `container` is clicked, iterates all the children views of the respective container and collects all the text from any views that are `TextView`.

This helps the user copy all the text inside a specific section for debugging purposes with a single click.

However, I am having a hard time replicating this mechanism when using compose.

I have already recreated the above layout with pure compose, for example:

```kotlin
(...)

ListItem(
    modifier = Modifier.clickable {
        // no way to get headlineContent and supportingContent here
    },
    headlineContent = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.my_label)) },
    supportingContent = { 
        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.my_text)) 
        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.my_text2)) 
        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.my_text3)) 
    },
)
(...)
```

But when it comes to implementing the `onclick` mechanism to iterate all the children of the container, and extract text from any that are `Text`, I cannot find a way to achieve this.

I got as far as using the `Modifier.clickable {}`, but there is no reference to the `ListItem`, or any of the children in it.

There can be 1 or more `Text` per each content inside the `ListItem`, so simply creating another function that stores the single string from each content is just not going to work.

The content of many of these is dynamic, but the labels themselves are static, so the helper function simplified this process significantly since I would no longer need to manually code every single click action for each container, accounting for text that can be dynamically changed.

Is this not possible to achieve with compose in as a simple way as in kotlin? If it is, how can it be done?

NOTE: Some of the `Text` may have their own unique customization, so any workaround that stores strings passed to a custom `ListItem` is just not going to work for my case, that is why I focused on a way to loop or iterate any `Text` inside the `ListItem`

Answer (score 1):

You can just create another function that provides exactly the kind of API surface you want:

```
@Composable
fun ListItem(
  headlineId: @StringRes Int,
  supportingId: @StringRes Int,
  onClick: (headlineText: String, supportingText: String) -> Unit
) {
  val headlineText = stringResource(headlineId)
  val supportingText = stringResource(supportingId)
  ListItem(
    modifier = Modifier.clickable {
        onClick(headelineText, supportingText)
    },
    headlineContent = { Text(text = headlineText) },
    supportingContent = { Text(text = supportingText) }
  )
}
```

Which you can then use like:

```
ListItem(R.string.my_label, R.string.my_text) { headlineText, supportingText ->
  // Now you can access the text of each
}
```

Of course, you could instead pass the resource IDs rather than the Strings to your listener if that's what your onClick listener wants - you're in control over what level of abstraction you want to expose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that will only work if I have 1 single string for the headline content and 1 single string for the supporting content. In my case each one can have multiple `Text` views inside each content which makes it impossible to use with this solution, and that is why I specifically focused on looping all the `Text` inside the `ListItem`. Perhaps my question can be improved to make this clearer, sorry about that, I will take care of it right away.

Comment: So take two lists of headers and supporting texts, they don't have to be single texts if you don't want them to be

Comment: That will just overcomplicate things, some of these `Text` can have their unique customizations, your suggestion will not work.

Answer (score 1):

It might not as simple as you want, you can define classes for text data like below.

```kotlin
sealed class TextData(val string: String) {
    @SuppressLint("ComposableNaming")
    @Composable
    // default composable function of text data
    // to be able to override make it open
    open fun toTextCompose() {
        Text(text = string)
    }

    
    class HeadlineContent(string: String) : TextData(string) {
        @SuppressLint("ComposableNaming")
        @Composable
        // just overrode to show you can make different text compose for a specifiy text data
        override fun toTextCompose() {
            Text(text = string, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        }
    }

    class SupportingContent(string: String) : TextData(string)
}
```

You can define other classes for additional data as you want.

With these classes you can filter data and compose.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ListItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    textDataList: List<TextData>,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Column(modifier = modifier.clickable { onClick() }) {
        // make a composable function for headline contents if necessary
        textDataList.filterIsInstance<TextData.HeadlineContent>().forEach { it.toTextCompose() }

        Divider()

        // make a composable function for supporting contents if necessary
        textDataList.filterIsInstance<TextData.SupportingContent>().forEach { it.toTextCompose() }
    }
}
```

Lastly, to retrieve a clipboard string from a list easily, make a extension function.

```kotlin
// it will return a string of the below format
// HeadlineContent: SupportingContent1 SupportingContent2 ...
val List<TextData>.clipboardString: String get() = joinToString(separator = " ") {
    it.string + when (it) {
        is HeadlineContent -> ":"
        is SupportingContent -> ""
    }
}
```

```kotlin
val textDataList = listOf(
    TextData.HeadlineContent("Headline content"),
    TextData.SupportingContent("Supporting content"),
    TextData.SupportingContent("Hello world!"),
)

ListItem(
    textDataList = textDataList,
    onClick = {
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            textDataList.clipboardString,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
)
```

The result of the above code is like

[image]